# C++ sscanf_s values not correct

Tags: c++, string

I'm using sscanf_s like so:

```
    double a = 0;
    double b = 0;
    sscanf_s(elements[1].c_str(),"<%d,%d>", &a, &b);
    complex<double> first(&a,&b);
```

But the values i'm getting are 4.5 and 1.9 when I've entered 1,2.

Why is it going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the correct conversion specifier.  `%d` is for `int`.  `%lf` is for `double`.